# DateTime.add() doesn't effectively add the requested amount of time

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these small lines:

```
Timestamp timestamp = document.get("timestamp");
DateTime time = timestamp.toDate();
time.add(const Duration(hours: 3));
print(time);
```

And before adding hours this is time:
[image]

And after adding 3 hours its value is the same:
[image]

What can it be caused by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/add.html) of the `add` method you will see that it's not a setter, rather it returns a new `DateTime` so you need it to assign to a new value.

```dart
var threeHoursFromNow = time.add(const Duration(hours:3));
```